# The same Android notification is displayed over and over again for two people

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

Two people have reported notifications being displayed over and over again. One of them saw a notification 80 times. There are hundreds of users and these are the only two with this problem, and I can't recreate it. One of the devices is a Samsung A70 and the other one is unknown. How do I diagnose and fix this for these two people without access to their devices?

`MyFirebaseMessagingService`:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Bundle myExtrasBundle = new Bundle();

        Map<String, String> notificationMap = remoteMessage.getData();
        nhMessage = notificationMap.get(MESSAGE_KEY);

        myExtrasBundle.putString(MESSAGE_KEY, nhMessage);
        FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(this));
        Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                .setService(MyJobService.class)
                .setRecurring(false)
                .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
                .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(0, 0))
                .setReplaceCurrent(true)
                .setExtras(myExtrasBundle)
                .build();

        dispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
   }
```

`MyJobService`:

```
@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters job) {
    Bundle a = job.getExtras();
    String nhMessage = a.getString(MyFirebaseMessagingService.MESSAGE_KEY);
    sendNotification(nhMessage);
}


public void sendNotification(String message) {
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationHelper.MESSAGE, message);
    notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, notificationID, notificationIntent, 0);
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    String channelId = "testapp";
    CharSequence channelName = "Test App Channel";
    NotificationChannel notificationChannel = null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, importance);
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setTicker(message)
                    .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setLights(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary), 500, 2000)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                    .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

    notificationManager.notify(notificationID, builder.build());
}
```

EDIT: As someone suggested, I started saving a key to shared preferences and checking for it so that the next time it won't get past that point. The problem is still happening.

Comment: Do you track notifications using Firebase Console ?

Comment: @GaspardF I'm using Azure. I put both FCM keys and APNS keys there and it sends the notifications. I don't know how to track notifications using the Firebase console. I don't see any option to do that in the Firebase console.

Comment: But why you are calling 'sendNotification()' function using JobDispatcher?? I mean it can be directly used in 'onMessageReceived()'.

Comment: Have you added sent notification details, in database for further status? like (sent to `user` at `time` with `status`) This can be the way to find the problem from server side.

Comment: What is the necessary of using FirebaseJobDispatcher here? It may be the culprit.

Comment: @NaitikSoni I do so because apparently the problems I was previously having were because it was lost after a while.

Comment: @NaitikSoni I do that but I took them out of the code snippet to make it more readable. They never get into the database for the ones that this happens for.